# Pop up window won't show up for button action

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, model-view-controller

I am currently working on a web application that required a registration form. After the data entered in and click the button to submit the data, a pop up window will show up with specific data entered in the form and then the form can be reset for new entry.

I am working the project in VS 17 and I've used MVC empty project template to make my web application.

The coding as follow:

*HTML code used for button action*

```
<button type="submit" class="registerbtn" id="register" onclick="button_action()">Register</button>

<script>button_action();</script>
```

*JS file for pop up window :*

```
function button_action() {

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#register").submit(function () {
        $("#myModal").modal();
    });
});

}
```

*HTML code used to create pop up window modal :*

```
 @* model *@
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            @* model content *@
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header" style="padding: 35px 50px" ;>

                    <h3> THANK YOU FOR REGISTERING WITH NIKINI LEARNING </h3>
                </div>

                @* body of the model *@
                <div class="modal-body" style="padding: 40px 50px;">
                    <form role="form">

                        @* Customer Registration Reference No. display*@
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="crf">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                                Customer Registration No. :
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="crf" />
                        </div>

                        @* Customer Name DIsplay*@
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                                Customer Name :
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" />
                        </div>

                        @* Customer Contact No. Display*@
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="contact">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                                Contact No. :
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact" />
                        </div>

                        @* Customer Email Display*@
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                                Email address :
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" />
                        </div>

                        @* Customer registered course display*@
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="course">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                                Registered course :
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" />
                        </div>

                        @* Customer registered date display*@
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="date">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                                Registered date :
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" />
                        </div>

                        @* Course duration display*@
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="duration">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                                Course duration :
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" />
                        </div>

                        @* Course price display*@
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="duration">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                                Course price :
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" />
                        </div>

                        <h4><i>Please use your Customer Registration Reference Number (CRF) to do the payment </i></h4>
                    </form>

                    @* footer of the model *@
                    <div class="modal-footer">

                        @* edit button *@
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-submit btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> edit
                        </button>

                        @* new button *@
                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-submit btn-default pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> New
                        </button>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

When I click the button without filling the fields in the form, pop up window showed up. So, I've changed the click function in the JS code with submit. Then the pop up window won't show up when the data is not filled in required field but even after the data is filled and click the submit button, the form just reset and pop up window won't show up.

I need some advice to rectify this problem since this took so much time to complete my project.

Any other methods that I can use to do the same job also preferred.

Here's the whole code of the view for those who need:

```
@{
ViewBag.title = "Customer Registration";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Layout.cshtml";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<link href="~/Content/register.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/nav.css" />
<script src="~/Scripts/layout.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/register.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<navbar>

    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <a href="/Login/login">Login</a>
        <a href="/Payment/payment"> Payment </a>
        <a href="/Register/register" class="active">Customer Registration</a>
        <a href="/Details/course">Course Details</a>
        <a href="/Details/users">User Info</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myfunction()">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </a>
    </div>

</navbar>

@* Register form *@
<form>

    @* Main container *@
    <div class="container">

        @* form heading *@
        <p class="my_heading1">
            <b>
                Customer Registration Form
            </b>
        </p>
        <p class="my_text_type1">
            <i>
                Please fill out the form to Register in Nikini Learning Courses.
            </i>
        </p>

        @* Data entry container *@
        <div class="entry_container">
            @* status entry *@
            <label for="status"><b>Status</b></label>
            <input type="text" name="status" required />

            @*Name Entry *@
            <label for="name"><b>Name</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" name="name" required />

            @*Name with initials entry *@
            <label for="namei"><b>Name with initials</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Your name with initials" name="namei" required />

            @*NIC entry*@
            <label for="nic><b>NIC / Passport No. </b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your NIC / Passport No." name="nic" required />

            @*Contact No entry*@
            <label for="contact"><b>Contact No.</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your Mobile / Land line No." name="contact" required />

            @*Email entry*@
            <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

            @*Involvement type entry*@
            <label for="type"><b>Type:</b></label>
            <div class="checkboxes">
                <input type="checkbox" name="person" value="person" /><label>Personal</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="comp" value="comp" /><label>Company</label>
            </div>

            @*Address entry*@
            <label for="address"><b>Address</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your address here" name="address" required />

            @*Company / Institute Name entry*@
            <label for="Com_In"><b>Company / Institute Name</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your Company / Institute Name" name="Com_In" required />

            @*Job / Field of Study entry*@
            <label for="job_field"><b>Job title / Field of study</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your Job title / Field of Study" name="job_field" required />

            @*Course date entry*@
            <label for="date"><b>Starting date of the course</b></label>
            <input type="date" name="date" required />

            @*Course Name entry*@
            <label for="course"><b>Course Name</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter the course name" name="course" required />

            <p></p>

            @*Price entry*@
            <label for="price"><b>Course price</b></label>
            <input type="text" name="price" required />

            <p></p>

            @*Duration entry*@
            <label for="duration"><b>Duration of the course</b></label>
            <input type="text" name="duration" required />

        </div>

        @* submit button :
            - by clicking the button, a pop-up window will be displayed with the data entered to the database.
        *@

        <button type="submit" class="registerbtn" id="register" onclick="button_action()">Register</button>

        <script>button_action();</script>
    </div>
</form>

<div>

    @* model *@
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            @* model content *@
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header" style="padding: 35px 50px" ;>

                    <h3> THANK YOU FOR REGISTERING WITH NIKINI LEARNING </h3>
                </div>

                @* body of the model *@
                <div class="modal-body" style="padding: 40px 50px;">
                    <form role="form">

                        @* Customer Registration Reference No. display*@
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="crf">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                                Customer Registration No. :
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="crf" />
                        </div>

                        @* Customer Name DIsplay*@
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                                Customer Name :
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" />
                        </div>

                        @* Customer Contact No. Display*@
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="contact">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                                Contact No. :
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact" />
                        </div>

                        @* Customer Email Display*@
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                                Email address :
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" />
                        </div>

                        @* Customer registered course display*@
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="course">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                                Registered course :
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" />
                        </div>

                        @* Customer registered date display*@
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="date">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                                Registered date :
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" />
                        </div>

                        @* Course duration display*@
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="duration">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                                Course duration :
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" />
                        </div>

                        @* Course price display*@
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="duration">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                                Course price :
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" />
                        </div>

                        <h4><i>Please use your Customer Registration Reference Number (CRF) to do the payment </i></h4>
                    </form>

                    @* footer of the model *@
                    <div class="modal-footer">

                        @* edit button *@
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-submit btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> edit
                        </button>

                        @* new button *@
                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-submit btn-default pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> New
                        </button>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should include full your cshtml file to question

Comment: Why are your adding `$(document).ready(function ()` and `$("#register").submit(function () {` within your `button_action` method? Just use `function button_action() {$("#myModal").modal();}`

Comment: I've added my full cshtml file in the question. you can view.

Answer (score 0):

change button_action()  function  to below function

```
function button_action() {
        $("#myModal").modal();
}
```

Comment: it worked for button click. but i want only to pop up when the form is filled and then the submit button clicked.